# Шаблоны в Yii2 - как пользоваться?

Tags: php, yii2

Сразу прошу прощения, если глупый вопрос, но я так и не понял, есть ли такое в yii2, и если есть - то как им пользоваться. Что я имею ввиду: есть такой код:

```
foreach ($reviews as $rev){
    ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <div class="pm-testimonial-container">

                                <div class="pm-testimonial-quote-box">
                                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="pm-testimonial-text-box">
                                    <p>тут текст</p>
                                    <p class="pm-testimonial-name">Автор</p>
                                    <p class="pm-testimonial-title">Город</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?
                }
```

Вот я хочу вынести этот html код в шаблон, вместо динамического текста прописать что то типа `[city]`, `[author]` и `[text]`. И в цикле вызывать наподобие

```
echo $this->template('items', ['city'=>'City', 'author'=>'Kola', 'text'=>'Text']);
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: По умолчанию, Yii использует PHP в шаблонах, но вы можете настроить Yii на поддержку других шаблонизаторов,таких как Twig или Smarty, которые доступны в расширениях.

Answer (score 1):

Фиг его знает, как с шаблонами. Никогда не ставил их. Также, наверно: добавить в `composer.json`, обновить через `composer update` через консоль, подключить в конфигурации `config/web.php` шаблонизатор по гайду шаблонизатора, и в папке `views/` создавать файлы. Только с расширением другим. Наверно, типа `.tpl` или че там. Поставить подсветку синтаксиса этого шаблонизатора в свой блокнот. И фигачить `[city]`, `[author]` и `[text]`.

Могу привести примеры, как фигачить без шаблонизатора и без стиля битрикса с вкраплениями php-тегов (`<?php ?>`, `<?= ?>`) внутрь `html`. Тут хелпер `yii\helpers\Html` типа юзается. Вообще, обычно все решают виджеты

GridView DetailView

[image: GridView][image: DetailView]

Но я только с техническими сайтами работал, где такие виджеты только и нужны.

---

**Монструозно**

Файл `views/site/index.php`

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

foreach ($reviews as $review) {
    echo Html::beginTag('li');
        echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3']);
            echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-container']);
                echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-quote-box']);
                    echo Html::tag('i', '', ['class' => 'fa fa-quote-left']);
                echo Html::endTag('div');

                echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-text-box']);
                    echo Html::tag('p', $review->text);
                    echo Html::tag('p', $review->author, ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-name']);
                    echo Html::tag('p', $review->city, ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-title']);
                echo Html::endTag('div');

            echo Html::endTag('div');
        echo Html::endTag('div');
    echo Html::endTag('li');
}
?>
```

Файл `controllers/SiteController.php`

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Reviews;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($id)
    {
        $reviews = Reviews::find()
            ->alias('t')
            ->where(['t.testimonial_id' => $id])
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', ['reviews' => $reviews]);
    }
}
?>
```

---

**Со вторым шаблоном**

Файл `views/site/index.php`

```
<?php
foreach ($reviews as $review) {
    echo $this->render('_testimonial', ['review' => $review]);
}
?>
```

Файл `views/site/_testimonial.php`

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

echo Html::beginTag('li');
    echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3']);
        echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-container']);
            echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-quote-box']);
                echo Html::tag('i', '', ['class' => 'fa fa-quote-left']);
            echo Html::endTag('div');

            echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-text-box']);
                echo Html::tag('p', $review->text);
                echo Html::tag('p', $review->author, ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-name']);
                echo Html::tag('p', $review->city, ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-title']);
            echo Html::endTag('div');

        echo Html::endTag('div');
    echo Html::endTag('div');
echo Html::endTag('li');
?>
```

Файл `controllers/SiteController.php`

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Reviews;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($id)
    {
        $reviews = Reviews::find()
            ->alias('t')
            ->where(['t.testimonial_id' => $id])
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', ['reviews' => $reviews]);
    }
}
?>
```

---

**С виджетом**

Файл `views/site/index.php`

```
<?= app\components\widgets\Testimonial(['reviews' => $reviews]) ?>
```

Файл `components/widgets/Testimonial.php`

```
<?php
namespace app\components\widgets;

use yii\helpers\Html;

class Testimonial extends yii\base\Widget
{
    public $reviews;

    public function init()
    {
        if (!isset($this->reviews)) {
            throw new \yii\base\Exception("Property \$reviews must be set.");
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        foreach($this->reviews as $review) {
            echo Html::beginTag('li');
                echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3']);
                    echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-container']);
                        echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-quote-box']);
                            echo Html::tag('i', '', ['class' => 'fa fa-quote-left']);
                        echo Html::endTag('div');

                        echo Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-text-box']);
                            echo Html::tag('p', $review->text);
                            echo Html::tag('p', $review->author, ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-name']);
                            echo Html::tag('p', $review->city, ['class' => 'pm-testimonial-title']);
                        echo Html::endTag('div');

                    echo Html::endTag('div');
                echo Html::endTag('div');
            echo Html::endTag('li');
        }
    }
}
```

Файл `controllers/SiteController.php`

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Reviews;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($id)
    {
        $reviews = Reviews::find()
            ->alias('t')
            ->where(['t.testimonial_id' => $id])
            ->all();

        return $this->render('index', ['reviews' => $reviews]);
    }
}
?>
```